# Mysql INNER JOIN update product category

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem on my MYSQL update query. I have two tables: one named product and one named product_category. Example:

Tableproduct

```
productid weight
1.                0.00
2.                0.00
3.                0.00
```

Tableproduct_category

```
productid categoryid
1.               77
1.               78
2.               86
2.               87
3.               40
```

The idea is that I want to update the weight of a certain product depending on the product category it belongs to. The following query works fine for parent categories, which have a lower number. However for subcategories the query seems to skip them. Is there anyway to check all combinations of product_id and category_id to set weight for the category_id values 78 and 87? Thanks in advance!

My query so  far:

```
UPDATE product
INNER JOIN product_to_category 
ON product.product_id=product_to_category.product_id 
Set weight = case 
           when product_to_category.category_id = '78' then '99.00000000'
           when product_to_category.category_id = '87' then '99.00000000'
end;
```

Comment: Both images are the same. Please post your data as plain text instead of images.

Comment: Where are subcategories in your table?

Comment: You need to add an `ELSE` clause to your `CASE`, otherwise all the other products will get their weight set to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to react. I thought images would be more clear because of the layout. All categories are given by a number, for example 77 could be the main category and 78 the subcategory.

Comment: Use code formatting to display a text table neatly. Anyway, how does the query know that `77` is a category while `78` is a subcategory?

Comment: The query itself doesnt know that, but my goal is to set for certain categoryIds a weight to the products. The issue I have here is that the query only works for the first categoryid which is matched for the productid.

Comment: Your query IS checking all combinations. But one category can undo what another category changed it to.

Comment: The rows are processed in an arbitrary order, and the final result is whatever came from the last category it processed.

Comment: Thanks again for your input. Do you have an idea to only update when listed in the case structure? Since products are in main categories and subcategories a maincategory query would overwrite the subcategorie query, and I would like to have that the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` clause that limits the matches to the cases you care about.

```
UPDATE product AS p
INNER JOIN product_to_category AS pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
SET weight = case pc.category_id
        when 78 then '99.00000000'
        when 87 then '99.00000000'
end
WHERE pc.category_id IN (78, 87)
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! Thank you very much.